# You bet 5 on the first dozen numbers and your friend bets 10 on red in a game of roulette. What is the covariance of the bets?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, covariance

When I calculated the answer to this, I got $Cov(X,Y) = 0$. 
This is because $$Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$$ $$= (10)(5)(1/6) - 10(5)(1/6) - 10(5)(1/3) + 10(5)(1/3) - 0 $$ $$ = 0 $$
However, I think there must be a mistake in my calculation because this implies that the two bets are independent. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I know understand why these two bets are independent if there are 36 slots. However, I am not trying to figure out if these bets are independent if there are 38 slots (American Roulette). I think they should be for the same reason the bets were independent with 36 slot roulette, but this is not what my covariance calculation shows.

$$Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$$ $$= (10)(10)(6/38) - 10(10)(6/38) - 10(5)(12/38) + 10(5)(14/38)$$ $$ = 2.49 $$

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: On a roulette wheel with no $0$s, the two bets are independent, since half of each dozen are red.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that there are $36$ possible outcomes, half of which are red the other half black. Also let's assume (I think this should hold in general) that there are $6$ red numbers in the first dozen numbers.

So lets denote the roulette outcome with $R$ and define
$$
X= \begin{cases}1, \quad \text{if $R$ is red},\\
0, \quad \text{if $R$ is black}, \end{cases} 
Y = \begin{cases} 1, \quad R \leq 12 \\
 0, \quad R > 12. \end{cases}
$$
we have 
$$
\Bbb P( X = 1) = \frac12, \quad \Bbb P (Y = 1) = \frac 13, \quad
\Bbb P(XY = 1) = \frac 6 {36} = \frac 16.
$$
Therefore
$$
\text{Cov}(5X, 10Y) = 50 \cdot \biggl( \frac 16 - \frac 12 \cdot \frac13 \biggr)= 0.
$$ 
So the covariance is zero, but this does not automatically imply that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
For independence you need to show that
$$
\Bbb P(X = x, Y=y) = \Bbb P(X=x) \cdot \Bbb P (Y=y), \quad x,y \in\{0,1\}.
$$
An easy calculation shows that $X$ and $Y$ are indeed independent.

Comment: I'm having trouble extending this idea to versions of roulette such as European Roulette, which uses 37 slots. To me, based on your explanation, it would make sense that the same events are also independent for European roulette. However, I am getting a covariance not equal to 0. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Maybe if you update your question and also put your calculations there we could help you more

Comment: Updated! thanks